Java code with Kafka stream api help WindowBy
I have a scenario where there is a Kafka producer streaming app producing json payload to a topic.
I want to create a stream application where it should do a count for every message that arrive into that topic during every one hour. And towards the end of every one hour it should call a method that should create a sample payload that says the count . Count may vary based on time window. I took help from chatgpt and copilot.
Nothing seems to be working. Need a sample Java application for the same.
Many thanks

Take a look at Windowing in kafka streams: https://kafka.apache.org/37/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing

If you have multiple consumers, you should use global storage with consistency. like Redis.
